# Could bound methods be implemented without instantiating MethodType on each call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binding, cpython, internals

As the docs say, functions defined in the class body are bound to class instance on demand (that is, when they're called by that instance); function object is a non-data descriptor.

This is indeed the case:

```py
>>> class X:
...     def foo(self): 1
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> print(hex(id(x.foo)))  # 0x7fe59020fa40
... after several seconds ...
>>> print(hex(id(x.foo)))  # 0x7fe59020fbc0 <- different!
>>> print(x.foo is x.foo)  # False
```

Pure Python equivalent of function's `__get__` is:

```py
def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
    "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
    if instance is None:
        return self
    return MethodType(self, instance)
```

Wouldn't it be more efficient not to create an instance of MethodType, but instead just return a small wrapper? In pure Python:

```py
def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
    "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return self(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    return new_func if instance is not None else self
```

Naturally, all of this isn't written in pure Python but instead, in CPython case, it's written in C; there are probably various shortcuts on the way. But surely in C (for CPython) defining a small wrapper function is faster than instantiating a MethodType? Or not?

I'm curious why wasn't this way chosen... What drawbacks does it have, compared to instantiating MethodType on each call?

Comment: Notice you could have simply written `x.foo is x.foo` (which returns False) to see that `x.foo` creates a new instance each time.   Your code creates a new closure of `new_func` each time `get` is called, whether or not `instance` is None, so I'm not sure how it's in any way better.

Comment: @FrankYellin it may very well not be better - in any way; but I wonder whether creating a closure would be more efficient (in terms of time/memory) than instantiating MethodType? In the end it wasn't chosen as default implementation, and it's interesting to know why. I've done a bit of searching, but haven't found the relevant discussion(s)